# Equivalent function for snr() from MatLab in Python

Tags: python, matlab, signals

There is a function in MATLAB [`snr(noisy_signal,sampling_frequency)`](https://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/snr.html#d118e185693) which computes SNR given just the corrupted noisy signal and the sampling frequency used. Is there an equivalent function in python?

Comment: Apparently scipy have an implementation, here's the doc https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.signaltonoise.html

Comment: Why not just computing it yourself instead of loading a package?

Comment: I want to reproduce the exact results from Matlab. I've looked at the code that function has. It looked too complicated for me. So, I was wondering if there is already a function or code available.

Comment: It would be good if there is a description of the algorithm and parameters the MATLAB ```snr``` function uses so I can reproduce it in Python.